# Android admob example interstitial memory leak

Tags: android, memory-leaks, admob, android-2.3-gingerbread, interstitial

I am actually experiencing a heap problem while using interstitials (2.3 Nexus One).
I am able to reproduce the problem using the admob sample from Google play (android sdk). I have just set my ad id and my device id as a test device (I also have the problem without doing setting the test device id).

- Just launch the sample, choose interstitial, Load, Display, Close.
- Now in DDMS you can see a given amount of Allocated memory after having triggered the GC. (in my case 3.421 MB)
- Then if I keep on repeating the Load, Display, Close operation, I see that the Allocated size on the heap just keeps on increasing. After some launches I reach 3.936 MB, and it never seems to stop.
  I DO NOT change the phone orientation in between or do anything fancy.

I have tried changing new InterstitialAd(this) to new InterstitialAd(getApplicationContext()) as suggested in some other questions, but it does not change the problem.

On a 4.4.2 emulator the problem seems to exist too (I say seem because as the emulator is really slow it is hard to perform the operation a big number of times).

Of course I have the same problem with my real application. In my real app I also tried recreating the interstital before each loading (after having removed its listener) but the problem is exactly the same, so my guess is that it is not the interstitial instance itself that leaks, but perhaps the web view, or one of admob threads.

In my real application this causes a crash when loading a "big" bitmap (a 800*560 png) because of a OutOfMemoryError failed to allocate... so I am afraid that this may also leak some native memory (which is used for bitmap allocation in 2.3)

EDIT : It seems to leak some native memory indeed, but a very samll quantity.

Comment: What Admob SDK are you using? 6.4.1 or earlier or the one from Google Play Services?

Comment: The one from Google Play Services (latest version).

Comment: @Consign could you solve this problem? It still happens and it causes every single process (including gmail, etc..) to die because of memory problems...

Comment: I just managed to further reduce the memory footprint of my app. Because of that and of my use of interstitials, it would take a tremendous amount of time for the interstitials to cause a memory error. Otherwise I think the problem is still there, sorry...